# Laravel doesn't take my class as a class

Tags: php, class, laravel, laravel-4, syntax-error

## The error message I received:

[image]

## My setups:

I've created a `classes` folder in `app` folder and created `Alert.php` inside `app\classes`.
In `app\start\global.php` the code is like this:

```
ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(
    app_path().'/commands',
    app_path().'/controllers',
    app_path().'/models',
    app_path().'/database/seeds',
    app_path().'/classes', // This line is the one I've added.
));
```

In `composer.joson`:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php",
        "app/classes"
    ]
```

After this I've ran `composer dump-autoload`.
And I've added `'Alert'=>'Alert'` in `aliases` array in `app\config\app.php`.
My class in `app\classes\Alert.php`:

```
<?php
class Alert {
    static function new($type, $message){
        if(Session::has("alert_type") && Session::has("alert_message")) {
            $alert_type = Session::get("alert_type");
            $alert_message = Session::get("alert_message");
        } else {
            $alert_type = array();
            $alert_message = array();
        }
        $alert_type[] = $type;
        $alert_message[] = $message;
        Session::flash("alert_type", $alert_type);
        Session::flash("alert_message", $alert_message);
    }
}
```

In `filters.php`:

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest()) {
        $alert_type = "danger";
        $alert_message = "<strong>Error: </strong>You need to sign in before continue.";
        Alert::new($alert_type, $alert_message);
        return Redirect::intended('/');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new` is a [reserved keyword](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php) in PHP. Use another name for your static method, and you'll be fine.